# Why a jqueryAjax callback function doesn't need to be invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web-frontend

I have been taught that a function with parameters can only be invoked if I pass it parameters but recently I got into this Jquery-Ajax thing and things look bit different. An example in a tutorial does this:

```
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
  if (statusTxt == "success")
    alert("External content loaded successfully!");

  if (statusTxt == "error")
    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
```

noticed the function with three parameters? yes, that one. The confusion is that its parameters are getting passed/mapped from nowhere apparently and yet it's been used inside the IF and alert and it works. How ? I mean how?

Comment: They're getting passed from the `load` function. `load` ends with something like `callback(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr)` where `callback` is your defined function above. Here's a simple callback example: https://jsfiddle.net/5gu37wo7/

Comment: If you check the jQuery source you can see where the function is getting called from: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.load. It's the `complete` handler of the AJAX request for those too lazy to click :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not right,
In JavaScript you can call a function which is waiting params without sending any:

```js
function sum(x, y) {
  alert(x + y);
}

sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first assumption is false, as [mentioned here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) :

> - A JavaScript function does not perform any checking on parameter values (arguments).
> - JavaScript functions do not check the number of arguments received.

So, the callback will be called with 1, 2 or 3 parameters (or it could even be 0).

And it is the [JQuery load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that will call your callback when the call will be done.